# Sql Query to return 3 rows for every entry with the same value in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK, I'm a little outta practice on SQL Queries here, I have a table with thousands of entries. 
Each row has a unique Id but there is a column named EquipmentId which is not unique and would be present in several rows. I want to return 3 rows for every EquipmentId and if there is less the than 3 entries for an EquipmentID I want those too. ..... make sense ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) `+` [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY EquipmentId  ORDER BY ID ) RN
     FROM TableName
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 3 
ORDER BY EquipmentId
```

Comment: Just to add to that is there a way to group the returns so I can see the entries grouped into 3's.

Answer (score 0):

Using subqueries you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT *, Rank() 
     OVER 
         (PARTITION BY equipmentid
          ORDER BY ID) Rank
     FROM stack) AS a 
WHERE
    rn <= 3
```